# In cucumber how we pass data in example keyword through database

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-serenity

I want to pass data in example keyword through the database, for example, I have one scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: login with valid credential
    Given Enter "username"
    And Enter "password"
    When click on submit
    Then navigate on home page

Examples:
    |username | password |
    |test1    | *****    |
```

In Example keyword i want to pass data in through database how we do please help me................

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you combine the steps where you enter the username and password into a single step, you can query the database to fill in the password:

```
When I log in as user "<username>"
```

The definition for this step should:

1. Query the database for the user passed in as an argument to the step
2. Type the username in the form field
3. Type the password in the form field, which you should have gotten using the database query in step 1 above
4. Submit the login form